# Simulate click on a minimized program

Tags: window, mouse-click

I was wondering if it is possible to simulate a click on a computer program that is not visible/is running as a background process. I am NOT looking for code (although I would happily see some if you have it lying around,) but just want to know if in theory a computer can do such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There are various ways, in fact, though most will require an additional program or programming language.

There is one way that does not however, which is why this question is not Off-Topic here on SuperUser.

1. Open the task manager
2. Select the program
3. Right click on it
4. Press Switch to

If you are using the expanded view (More details), then you have to do the following:

1. Click on the > in front of the program to expand it
2. Select the sub program
3. Right click on it
4. Press Switch to

The above will not work for background processes, and only in the Processes tab,not in the Details tab.

A program that does not have an interface, or otherwise is running in the background, cannot be brought to the front, and cannot receive mouse clicks because it doesn't have an actual form. It is still possible to control such program, but only by the use of a programming language, as it requires an API call. If you want to learn more about this last part, please create a new question in the Stack Overflow section of Stack Exchange, as that is where programming questions belong.